# SSRS expression for hiding/showing text boxes

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created an SSRS report.

In this report I have created a dataset called: DataSet1. DataSet1 contains two columns: EntityId (integer) and Name (Varchar). I would like to show a textbox if one of the values in the EntityId column is "27".

So I want to write an expression that does this:

If one of the rows in DataSet1 has a EntityId value of 27, then show the textbox, else hide the textbox.

From reading some other similar questions, I think counting the rows is probably the way to go. So instead it might be something like:

Count the rows where DataSet1.EntityId = 27. If the number of rows is more than 0 then show the SSRS textbox, else hide the textbox.

Any help with the expression would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with a simple expression.

Set the `hidden` property of the textbox to

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!EntityID.Value = 27,1,0), "DataSet1") = 0
```

All we are doing here is, starting from the inner expression...

1. Check if `EntityID` = 27, if it does return 1 else return 0.
2. Do this for each instance within the scope `"DataSet1"` (your entire dataset)
3. Sum the results
4. Test if the result is zero

This will return `True` if the result is zero (no rows = 27) and therefore hide the textbox

**Note:** the dataset name must be enclosed in quotes and is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was exactly what I needed, as I have to do this for a few different datasets and parameters. I think was getting a bit confused with the order of the elements in the expression.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answered your question would you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the Vote Up/Down buttons to the left).

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the expression simple, I would suggest to add the corresponding flag directly to the DataSet. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  EntityID int
 ,Title nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(10, 'Test 1')
,(27, 'Test 2')
,(27, 'Test 3')
,(11, 'Test 4')
,(15, 'Test 5')
,(15, 'Test 6')
,(27, 'Test 7')

SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN EntityID = 27 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS flag
  FROM @t
```

The column `flag` is 0 if no EntityID 27 is found and > 0 if this ID is found, so your expression would be something like `if flag > 0 then...`.